# What is the meaning of "às tantas"?

Tags: significado

What are the meanings of ‘às tantas’ in the following sentences?

> - Tivemos tanto trabalho com este processo no Tribunal, mas ***às tantas*** isto não vai dar em nada.
> - Há já três dias que me andas a falar do barco. ***Às tantas*** ainda mo queres é vender.
> - Chegou a casa ***às tantas*** da noite.

In what other contexts is it used?

Answer (score 9):

Segundo o Aulete, pode significar:

> Às/ Pelas tantas
>
> 1. Em certo momento (indeterminado); em certa hora do dia (não informada): *Estavam conversando e às tantas / lá pelas tantas quis saber onde ela morava.*
> 2. Em hora ou momento tardios: *Chegou às tantas / pelas tantas da madrugada*

A tua última frase corresponde claramente a 2., mas as outras duas não encaixam muito bem em 1 porque a ideia temporal está bastante esbatida.

> Tivemos tanto trabalho com este processo no Tribunal, mas às tantas isto não vai dar em nada.

Poderíamos dizer:

> Tivemos tanto trabalho com este processo no Tribunal, mas *depois de tudo isto, provavelmente* não vai dar em nada.

A outra:

> Há já três dias que me andas a falar do barco. Às tantas ainda mo queres é vender.
>
> Há já três dias que me andas a falar do barco. *Ao fim e ao cabo*/*Por fim estou a ver que* ainda mo queres é vender.

Em ambas as frases há uma noção de conclusão incerta e inesperada.

Comment: Pelos vistos o Aulete não indica um significado de _às tantas_ corrente em Portugal, que é simplesmente _possivelmente._ É este o significado de _às tantas_ nas frases 1 e 2.

Comment: Pensei que esta pergunta pudesse ter interesse para quem esteja a aprender português, já que a resposta não é fácil de tirar de um dicionário. Por isso a escrevi em inglês. Mas as vossas respostas são em português. Preferem que refaça a pergunta em português? (também @Jacinto)

Comment: É a tua pergunta. Eu ainda cheguei a pensar se deveria responder em inglês, um Sérgio Pereira poderia ser filho de portugueses criado no estrangeiro, mas acabei por decidir que quem não me compreendesse poderia sempre pedir esclarecimentos adicionais.

Answer (score 6):

O [Priberam define **às tantas**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tantas) como:

> (a) Em hora indeterminada; a certa altura (ex.: a população, às tantas, revoltou-se).
> (b) Em hora tardia; muito tarde (ex.: chegou a casa às tantas; a festa durou até às tantas da manhã).
> (c) Provavelmente; se calhar (ex.: às tantas, ele pensa que eu vou pagar o jantar).

O significado (c) parece não ser corrente no Brasil e não figura no [Aulete Digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/tantas), mas é muito comum em Portugal. [**Se calhar** já aparece no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/calhar) com o significado de *talvez* (restrito a Portugal), *provavelmente*, e *oxalá* (que eu desconhecia). O significado relevante de *às tantas* as frases (1) e (2)  é o (c). Poderíamos escrevê-las como:

> (1) Tivemos tanto trabalho com este processo no Tribunal, mas **às tantas** isto não vai dar em nada.
> (1a) (...) mas **possivelmente** isto não vai dar em nada.
> (1b) (...) mas **se calhar** isto não vai dar em nada.
>
> (2) Há já três dias que me andas a falar do barco. **Às tantas** ainda mo queres é vender.
> (2a) (...) **Provavelmente** ainda mo queres é vender.
> (2b) (...) **Se calhar** ainda mo queres é vender.
> (2c) (...) Mas queres vender-mo ou quê?

Na frase (3), (b) é o significado relevante:

> (3) Chegou a casa **às tantas** da noite.
> (3a) Chegou a casa **já muito tarde** durante a noite.
> (3a) Chegou a casa **a altas horas** da noite.

Especialmente para indicar acontecimentos futuros fica bem **lá para as tantas**:

> Só vai chagar a casa lá para as tantas da noite.
> (Ou simplesmente) Só vai chegar a casa lá para as tantas.

Comment: Certo, mas eu acrescentaria que quer no significado 1. do Aulete quer como "possivelmente", há uma ideia de qualquer coisa inesperada ou súbita.

Comment: Esta observação deu-me que pensar! Acho que está bem observado, mas como sempre há qualificações e exceções. _Às tantas_ como _a certo momento_ é o mais fácil. Indica quase sempre que uma coisa é algo inesperada e súbita. Se alguma coisa acontece em certo momento, tem que ser súbita. Mas este exemplo parece-me fugir à regra: _Agora já durmo bem na casa nova, mas ao princípio não conseguia dormir com o barulho do trânsito. Já sabes como é, uma pessoa às tantas habitua-se e depois já não nota._

Comment: _Às tantas_ como _possivelmente_ normalmente não indica nada de súbito, mas frequentemente indica algo inesperado, ou pelo menos alguma oposição entre o que vem antes e depois do _às tantas_, frequentemente mas não necessariamente reforçado por _mas_. Modificando ligeiramente o exemplo acima: _esse processo judicial vai dar uma trabalheira, e às tantas não dá em nada_. Há uma certa oposição entre uma coisa dar muito trabalho e poder não dar resultado. Exeções vêm a seguir.

Comment: _Às tantas amanhã vou à praia_ parece não ter nada de inesperado ou oposição entre o quer que seja. Eu podia dizer que há uma oposição entre eu não ter tomado uma decisão (implícito na frase) e poder ir, mas seria altamente rebuscado.

Comment: _Às tantas_ serve para introduzir especulações em que normalmente também não é fácil encontrar oposições. _Num documentário sobre a guerra fria traduziram 'they wanted to kill détente,' que quer dizer 'desanuviamento,' por 'eles queriam matar a cidade!' Ora! Às tantas os tradutores são mal pagos e tem que fazer aquilo a correr!'_ Aqui os _às tantas_ introduz um explicação especulativa para a observação anterior, mas não é surpreendente nem em oposição ao que se disse antes. O exemplo acima do barco parece-me cair nesta categoria.

Comment: Este tipo de palavras com uma componente temporal mas que também servem como partículas modais são sempre difíceis de analisar. Outros exemplos são "ainda", "sempre", "afinal". Em holandês, é comum juntar 3 ou 4 partículas modais (algumas delas também com sentido temporal como nog, even, eens) duma só vez e já muita tinta correu sobre o significado individual de cada uma delas. Mas de volta a "às tantas"...

Comment: Primeiro exemplo: concordo que aí "às tantas" está muito esvaziado de qualquer aspeto modal e não significa muito mais do que "em dada altura (indeterminada)". Nessa frase ainda há uma ideia de oposição: *Não conseguia dormir com o barulho do trânsito, mas às tantas uma pessoa habitua-se*, mas nesta claramente não: *não conseguia dormir como o barulho, e estás tantas já estava com problemas de saúde*.

Comment: "Às tantas amanhã vou à praia" é-me difícil de analisar sem contexto. Mas em "não sei bem que fazer amanhã, às tantas (ainda) vou à praia", há claramente uma ideia de que essa é uma opção inesperada.

Quanto há última eu argumentaria que há de facto uma ideia adversativa -- neste caso contra o pano de fundo de que a gente espera que os tradutores sejam competentes.

Comment: A oposição entre a competência esperada dos tradutores é relativamente ao erro de tradução. _Às tantas_ não introduz essa oposição; introduz é uma explicação especulativa para o que se disse antes, tal como no teu exemplo dos problemas de saúde. Vou incluir algumas das nossas conclusões no corpo da resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Respondo pelo uso de "às tantas" em **ptBr**.

Pouco se ouve essa expressão por aqui.  Na maioria das vêzes sob a forma **"lá pras tantas"** ou **"já la pras tantas"**, significando "já tendo passado bastante tempo".
Ex: **"Quando, já lá pras tantas, ninguém mais aguentava esperar, resolveram abrir os portões.**

As três frases da pergunta são típicamente ptPT, não seriam ouvidos no Brasil construções do tipo preposição "a" + verbo no infinitivo ("andas a falar" ao invés de "andas falando").  "Mo queres..." se algum dia foi usado no Brasil, deve ter sido há mais de 100 anos.

Comment: Então como usam "ainda mo queres é vender"?

Comment: @JorgeB.  De diversas formas.  "ainda queres vendê-lo", "estás querendo vendê-lo a mim", "ainda quéh vendê ele pra mim" (este último, completamente errado, é ouvido com frequencia no pt falado.

Comment: "ainda queres vende-lo" também se usa muito aqui.

Comment: @Centaurus Obrigado por esclarecer esta distinção entre ptPT e ptBr. De facto, não me consta que o sentido de 'possivelmente' seja usado no Brasil, assim como a expressão 'se calhar' também não.